# Delete an answer or close the question?

Tags: discussion

Earlier today I came across a [six year old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808816/are-html-comments-inside-script-tags-a-best-practice) that ends with:

> What do you do? Is this still considered a 'best practice?'

That alone could be considered a reason to close the question is it's opinion-based. But the issue I first encountered was with the [second most popular answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/808830/616443) (with 20+ upvotes) that consists entirely of:

> I've stopped doing it. At some point you just have to let go of your
>   NCSA Mosaic.

Six years ago this type of answer might have been allowed, but today something like this is best presented as a comment. I was surprised at how many upvotes this answer received, but figured that it probably received the bulk of its votes back when the rules on quality weren't as strict as they are now.

I flagged the answer, yet somehow it survived the review queue. My first question is, should this answer be deleted or converted to a comment? My second question is, should the question be closed as off-topic? At best the question only has historical value, and only a little at that, plus it's potentially a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204813/does-it-still-make-sense-to-use-html-comments-on-blocks-of-javascript).

Comment: Well as far as the answer goes, it's good enough to stay as is.  Maybe a downvote, since it doesn't really explain anything, but it does answer (or at least heavily imply) "no" to the question of "Is this a best practice".  As for the quesiton.... I don't know.  6yo questions are sometime treated differently.

Answer (score 9):

Do nothing.

There are no particular problems with this *old* question/answers. Detailed long answer has enough votes that bring it to the top, the rest have significantly less votes to ever surface. There is *not much value* to spend time fixing that answer, especially if you are looking for author to spend time on it.

Notes:

- the question was duplicate when it was created and in similar case now it likely would be closed as duplicate.
- if such answer is top voted for old question but there is much better answer with significantly less votes some action (edit/comment to update) may be useful (assuming question has large number of views).
- on recent questions/recent answer - downvote and/or comment seem to be appropriate assuming question is actually on-topic. Otherwise acting on question would be better (close/edit).

Answer (score 5):

The answer doesn't merit flagging in any way.  Posting an opinion based answer to an opinion based question doesn't make it an invalid answer; the problem is with the question.  If you feel that it's a low quality answer then the proper course of action is to downvote it.

Feel free to vote to close questions like these when you see them, but unless there's new activity sparking on the question, trying to close them is typically less important than closing newly asked questions.  Because of this, you should generally avoid actively searching out old inactive close-worthy questions to flag.  If you happen to come across one for some reason, feel free to handle it accordingly, but don't prioritize them.

Comment: _"If you feel that it's a low quality answer then the proper course of action is to vote to close it."_ How do you vote to close an answer?

Comment: _"you should generally avoid actively searching out old inactive close-worthy questions to flag.'_ Who said I was searching out "old inactive" questions?

Comment: @j08691 Nobody said you were actively searching out old questions.  Who said anyone claimed you did?

Comment: @j08691 To the first point, I've edited that line.

Answer (score 2):

Given elementary reading comprehension, an answer of "I've stopped doing it" is a clear "no" response to a question of "is it a best practice?"

Honestly, it's over-the-top officiousness like this that has me, someone who is apparently a top 0.18% contributor, mostly inactive and feeling like the quality of this site has descended precipitously from where it was in its first few years.

Comment: I understood some of those words @pnuts